# Want to change a dropdown into a check box which stores in the database

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I need to change this bit of code to a checkbox that stores the values in an array. How can this be done?

```
<div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">

                     <select name="category_id">
                         <?php
                            foreach($category_lists as $list){
                                if($list['id'] == $arr_collect['category_id']){
                                    $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
                                }else{
                                    $sel = null;
                                }
                                echo '<option value="'.$list['id'].'"'.$sel.'>'.$list['name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove out the `<select></select>` tags and try:

```
<?php

foreach($category_lists as $list)
    {
    if ($list['id'] == $arr_collect['category_id'])
        {
        $chk = 'checked';
        }
      else
        {
        $chk = '';
        }

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="' . $list['id'] . '" ' . $chk . '>' . $list['name'];
    }

?>
```

Then you can access it like:

```
<?php
$lists = $_POST['list'];

foreach($lists as $list_val)
    {
    echo $list_val; //prints all the checked values
    }
?>
```